# iOS Auto Layout confusion

Tags: ios, autolayout, scale

I am really stuck trying to figure out how to add items to an auto layout and have them scale so they are positioned in the same screen spaced no matter what device. For example in the below image I want the button to be positioned at C3 on 4", 4.7" and 5.5" iPhones. I also want the button to be two squares high and two square wide on each device.

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

**Edit**

I have just figured out that an items position can be scaled to the screen size by applying the constraint to the parents view center, setting the the constant to 0 and adjusting the constraints multiplier. However, it seems like a very laborious way to have an item scale to screen size. Is there not a simpler way.

Comment: Use the Aspect Ratio property in AutoLayout.

Comment: Use size class u will get that n then as per ratio

Comment: @PallaviLigade, this is achievable w/o size classes.

Answer (score 0):

You want to specify position as well as size of `button` proportional to size (width) of squares. As square width is determined by `superview` size, you want to have something like this:

```
button.width  = (superview.width / 9) * 2 
button.height = (superview.width / 9) * 2
button.x      = (superview.width / 9) * 2
button.y      = (superview.width / 9) * 2
```

Proportional width / height can be easily set in AutoLayout by adding equal width / height constraint and adjusting multiplier (once you have one dimension specified, you can specify the other via aspect ratio constraint).

Unfortunatelly, proportional position (spacing) cannot be specified in Autolayout directly. Workaround would be to use transparent `spacingView` attached to both `superview` and `button`, and setting its dimensions proportional to `supeview`.

```
V:[superview]-0-[spacingView]-0-[button]
H:[superview]-0-[spacingView]-0-[button]

spacingView.width  = superview.width / 4.5
spacingView.height = superview.width / 4.5
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see you have `checkers.jpg` image as a background, it that case you can't have any universal solution, you need to fix this position in any device size.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of what I achieved:

[image: example]

1. To keep button scaled in difference screens setup width and height for button to be equal of the widht/height of super view. Then setup multiplier to be 1:X where X is the numbers of squares on the screen.

[image: button widht/height]

2. To keep button proportionally positioned add 2 spacer views - one for top space and one for left (green and blue on my screenshot).
   Add constraints the next way:

(horizontal) `[superview left]-0-[left spacer]-0-[button]`

(vertical) `[superview top]-0-[top spacer]-0-[button]`

For width/height of spacer views do the same trick with equal width/height to superview:
[image: top spacer]
[image: left spacer]

Then to move button across the screen you only need to change multiplers of the spacer views.

Width of the button can be controlled through multiplier of equal width and equal height constraints from button to superview.

[image: 2 tiles width/height]